# I want to convert an image to greyscale 'by hand' using numpy functions

Tags: python-3.x

My function looks something like this:

```
def grey(img):
    r = img[:, :, 0]
    g = img[:, :, 1]
    b = img[:, :, 2]
    for row in r:
        for column in r:
            grey = (r[row, column] + g[row, column] + b[row, column])/3
            img[row, column] = grey
    return img
```

The error message I get is `ValueError: shape mismatch: value array of shape (3024,) could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (3024,3)`

I'm new to python and especially to arrays and I'm pretty much in the dark. Maybe the mean of the RGB value won't give a good shade of grey, but that's not really important.

Comment: if you are just doing the mean then do `img.mean(2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I was looking for was something like this:

```
def grey_scale(img):
    """Converts an image to grayscale"""
    avg = np.mean(img, axis=2)  # reads the RGB values and gets the average
    grey_img = np.dstack([avg, avg, avg]).astype('uint8')  # stacks the R, G and B channels
    return grey_img
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

img = mpimg.imread('test.jpg')

R, G, B = img[:,:,0], img[:,:,1],  img[:,:,2]
imgGray = 0.2989 * R + 0.5870 * G + 0.1140 * B
plt.imshow(imgGray, cmap='gray')
plt.show()
```

This should turn your image to grayscale :)

Comment: Thank you, it does work indeed. But what I'm trying to do is learn how to navigate numpy arrays and the mechanics of how an image works. Those values seem pretty random to me and don't really help with understanding anything.